# Increase google play store early access user limit

Tags: android, google-play, mobile-application

I have uploaded an app and registered in the early access program. But when the number of users downloaded the app reached 100, no more users can download the app even though they are on the same G-Suite domain.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

All of the [documents on this are here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?).

The purpose of early access is for testing and QA. If you need more than 100 users, you probably aren't just doing testing and QA. Your options are:

- If you want to run a closed test and manage them by email address do a "Closed test". You can have up to 2,000 users
- if you want anyone in the world to have early access run an "Open test"
- if you want to limit it to a particular domain only use [private apps](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145139)